# Creating date segments in redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create segments of date based on a flag.

Below is the table I currently have order by start_date,end_date.

| ID | start_date | end_date | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9659 | 5/18/2012 | 5/18/2012 | 0 |
| 9659 | 5/18/2012 | 5/18/2012 | 0 |
| 9659 | 6/8/2012 | 6/8/2012 | 0 |
| 9659 | 6/8/2012 | 6/8/2012 | 0 |
| 9659 | 8/25/2012 | 8/25/2012 | 1 |
| 9659 | 8/27/2012 | 8/27/2012 | 0 |
| 9659 | 10/27/2012 | 10/27/2012 | 1 |

I'd like to create a column named 'segment'. This column should be incremented whenever flag=1. How to achieve it? Below is the expected result.

| ID | start_date | end_date | flag | segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9659 | 5/18/2012 | 5/18/2012 | 0 | 1 |
| 9659 | 5/18/2012 | 5/18/2012 | 0 | 1 |
| 9659 | 6/8/2012 | 6/8/2012 | 0 | 1 |
| 9659 | 6/8/2012 | 6/8/2012 | 0 | 1 |
| 9659 | 8/25/2012 | 8/25/2012 | 1 | 2 |
| 9659 | 8/27/2012 | 8/27/2012 | 0 | 2 |
| 9659 | 10/27/2012 | 10/27/2012 | 1 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(flag) over (partition by id order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) + 1 as seqnum
from t;
```

This assumes that you want a separate enumeration per id.